# How to add vb classes into the class library?

Tags: vb.net, dll, visual-studio-2005, class-library

I made a new VS 2005 class library project and I added several VB.NET classes into it. However, when i compile the project and import the dll into my other projects, I cannot see my classes.

What do i do wrong, what should I do to add then in the compilation?

Comment: Are they definitely included and have an access modifier that allows them to be used across projects?

Comment: I added them with Add->Existing Item. Should I add then differently? @AFriend

Comment: What do you mean with _import_? The correct term is _referenced_ and that's not enough. You need also to use the _Import yournamespace_ statement to the source code of the files that want to use the classes

Comment: @Steve I added the dll usign Add Reference command->Browse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple reasons why that may happen, so without more information, it's impossible to say for sure why, but the most likely reasons which come to mind are:

- The classes in the class library may not be declared as `Public`.  If they are declared as `Friend` (or as `Private` if they are nested types), they will not be visible to other projects that consume that library.  The classes should be declared like this: `Public Class MyClass`
- The consuming code is not specifying the namespace.  Unless the namespace in which the classes are declared in the class library is the same as the code that's trying to call it, the consuming code needs to either import the class library's namespace, or it needs to fully qualify the class names when it uses them.  To import the namespace, at the top of the code file that uses the class, add a line like this: `Imports MyClassLibraryNamespace` (but with your actual namespace).  To fully qualify the class name inline, you can do it like this: `Dim myVariable As New MyClassLibraryNamespace.MyClass`

Answer (score 2):

Did you use an explicit access modifier (`Public` or `Friend`) on your classes in your class library? If not, it will default to `Friend`. That means that your classes are only visible within that assembly (class library).

So you might want to make certain specific classes in your class library public:

```
Public Class MyClass
    ...
End Class
```

Edit: As Steven Doggart pointed out, VB.NET classes are public by default. So this might not be an issue unless you explicitly used another access modifier.

Comment: What you said about the default accessibility is untrue.  While it's true that in C#, the default accessibility for a class is `internal` (the equivalent of `Friend`), in VB, the default for classes is `Public`.

Comment: Ah. Sorry about that. I haven't checked those defaults. I have been using VB.NET and C# in mixed solutions so often in the last years that I just always use an explicit access modifier to avoid these kind of mistakes. Thanks for the correction anyway.